# Why this code return empty list or fail? Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
primes :: [Int]
primes = sieve [2..]

sieve :: [Int] -> [Int]
sieve (p:xs)= p:sieve[x|x<-xs,x `mod` p /= 0]

f :: Int->Int
f n = head [x|x<-[0,(product (filter (<n) primes))..],x/=0,sum (map (x `mod`) [1..n]) == 0]
```

---

load into GHCi
and type "f 20"
fail...... plz help me

Comment: Select your code and press Ctrl-K or `{}` button to format it.

Comment: How does it fail? What does GHCi say?

Comment: Should this be `[2..n]`?  `(map (x 'mod') [1..n])1`

Comment: uhm... for the code, maybe infinite loop...

Comment: mydogisbox//
head [x|x<-[0,(procduct [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19])..],x/=0,sum (map (x `mod`) [1..20]) == 0]
this code is well performed..

Comment: oh......... i think, " filter (<40) primes " this code makes infinite loop.. when primes::generate infinite prime number list. how can fix it?

Comment: Use `takeWhile` instead of `filter`. But since your list is `[Int]`, the list isn't infinite, just very long. (And with the horrible algorithm used, it will take aeons to complete even if `Int` is 32 bits.)

Comment: @DanielFischer um.. another problem poped up!
when type "f 5" in ghci, 5 is not Int type.. and fail. But "let n = 5::Int; f n" it's fine

Comment: When you type `f 5`, the type of the literal is determined to be `Int` from the type of `f`. When you do something like `let n = 5` and then `f n`, then you may run into the monomorphism restriction, by which the value `n` must get a monomorphic type, and absent further constraints, that is by default `Integer`. You can bind `let n :: Int; n = 5` or `let n = 5 :: Int` to make `n` have type `Int`. Or `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` to have `n` be polymorphic.

Comment: @DanielFischer veryvery appreciate you. im learning programming in haskell. it's so beautiful for physicist,me. :). I got more one question, how to expand `f :: Int -> Int` to `f :: Int -> Integer` or `f :: Integer -> Integer`? e.g. case of former, ghci say `could not match expected type 'Integer' with actual type 'Int'`. i don't understand this message..

Comment: You would need to convert some things to `Integer` then for `f :: Int -> Integer`. The easiest thing would be to have `f :: Integer -> Integer` and just change all occurrences of the type `Int` to `Integer` in the above code.

Comment: @DanielFischer won't it just wrap around and continue going on? BTW it's not aeons, it's about 30,000 years I think, to get to the INT_MAX on 32 bit. :)

Comment: @WillNess The `Enum` instances for `Int`, `Word` and `IntN/WordN` stop at `maxBound`, so no wrap-around (but a pattern-match failure at `sieve []` finally). I'm a tad impatient, so my aeons might be shorter than yours ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer besides, it will run out of available memory much sooner probably. :) thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Will Not sure about "much" (depends of course on what "much" shall mean here too). With 4GB, it could chug on for quite a while. But yes, it would probably be OOM-killed before it reaches the end.

Comment: @Will It shouldn't be quadratic in space (even ignoring the logarithmic factors). You have one filter for each prime already encountered, so `O(k/log k)`.

Comment: @Daniel I'm ignoring logs. OK, if not, then (k/log k)^2. OK, so its not x1,000,000; it's x400,000. *Squared*. over 1MB, 160 GB. Not  a billion GB, but still... :) ahm, or maybe I'm completely off here, there's no squares involved. nevermind. :)

Comment: @Will, `715,064 bytes maximum residency` for a limit of 100,000, and `5,337,608 bytes maximum residency` for a million. Not quadratic.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, lower than linear. Looks like it's indeed about  k/log_k.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with `filter (< n) primes`. Since `primes` is an <s>infinite</s> very long<sup>1</sup> list, this takes a long time to terminate since it doesn't know that `(< n)` will eventually return `False` for all primes past a certain point in the list, so it has to keep checking the entire list.

```
> filter (< 20) primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19^CInterrupted.
```

Use `takeWhile (< n) primes` instead.

```
> takeWhile (< 20) primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> It's finite because of the type `[Int]`. If it was `[Integer]`, it would be infinite.</sub>